# AngularJS input element focus

Tags: html, angularjs, input, focus

Let's say I have several inputs on my page. Some radio buttons, some checkboxes and input type=text fields. I want the following:**I don't want to let user focus type=text fields until some variable is true.** Maybe there is solution like we could collect input=text fields in array and when user focuses one of that fields, unfocuse them. Thanks.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7b7yemz/483/)

here is example. Until `$scope.variableToEnableFocusOnInput` is false, I don't want `$scope.inputValue` to be focusable.

Answer (score 0):

This **ng-disabled** might be useful for your case.

Check this out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

There are a lot of examples out there too and it is simple enough to learn and use.

I modified this line of your code and the result looks like what you are asking.

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="!variableToEnableFocusOnInput" ng-model="inputValue">
```

Comment: thats right solution but not in my case. thanks anyways <3

Answer (score 0):

you can use an easy way to do that:-

assume you don't need to select input before select checkbox

```
  <form action="" name='checkForm'>
<input required type='checkbox' ng-model='checkboxInput' name='checkboxInput'>
<input type='text' ng-model='inputText' ng-disabled='checkForm.checkboxInput.$invalid'>
```